Does temporarily redirecting many pages (already ranking on 1st page) to a specific new page affect SEO?
We sell customized gift items on our e-commerce site. We want to get orders of specific products during some special occasions. This is because we have limited resources and thus face challenges in preparing and delivering a variety of orders, on time. So, We usually remove the unwanted products and show customers only a specific range of products which are possible to deliver on time.
To make this easier this year, Our team has come up with an idea.

Create a landing page with the limited products.
Temporarily redirect (302) all pages ranking on the 1st page of SERP to this new landing page - just for 5 days or less.
Then we will revert the redirects once the sale is over.

I am worried as this may affect the SEO efforts. Any thoughts on this? Your suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks.

Just like @Rohit mentioned below, this has a huge downside in that you are intentionally de-ranking your page. Even though this is only for <5 days, you have the potential to screw up your organic reach for much longer. I think it is easier to display a message that orders during this time might take longer to process rather than messing around with redirects for SEO. There is also a good chance that Google won't even take into account your changes until after your crunch period. If you want limited inventory, just leave your pages as is and indicate low or no stock at this time.

I will pass this suggestion on to the team. Thank you so much.

I think its a silly idea. The best thing for SEO is to be natural and not play games with the ranking.
Apart from the original confusion, and the possible loss of ranking, the redirection may persist for a while, if other sites are linking to the pages.

Thank you for your insights. Much appreciated.
